Opening Streamlit using os.system() command
I am creating an app in Streamlit at work. Because most of the people do not know anything about programming (including how to start Streamlit) I thought to create en executable file with a code that starts Streamlit.
This is my code:
import os

cmd = 'streamlit run main.py'

os.system(cmd)

Next I use pyinstaller to change it into an exe file. However, exe file opens and closes and Streamlit is not opened. How could I fix this? I also tried to use the absolute filepath to main.py - also doesn't work

Try running the .exe from terminal and check what is displayed.

I just downloaded the library and tested it myself.
In my experience you need to put in your email the first time your using steamlit.
Since the exe is an new instance of the library. You might need to put in your email address.

Excuse me, but what? Put email where? Our email?

Sorry typo. I meant your email address. When I used the library the Frist time the code only worked when I put my email in. So maybe check the output of the code by parenting it to the terminal
